# coclass in .idl import interface defined elsewhere?

Tags: c++, unmanaged, idl

I have an IDL file that defines a few interfaces followed by a coclass. Can I make this class import interfaces that are not defined in this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You need to use the `import` directive to load the .idl for the external interfaces, or use `importlib` to load the type library. Something like this:

```
import "otherlibrary.idl";

library MyLibrary
{
  coclass MyClass
  {
    interface OtherInterface;
  };
};
```

Or this:

```
library MyLibrary
{
  importlib "otherlibrary.tlb";

  coclass MyClass
  {
    interface OtherInterface;
  };
};
```

Comment: The importlib is exactly what I needed. Thanks!